# Setting the optional query parameters for the Users.messages.list

Tags: c#, .net, gmail-api

I'm trying to do an advanced search using the Gmail API, but I can't figure out how to set the parameters of the query. I want to do a search with the query `is:chat`, so all the returned messages will be only chat messages.

In the documentation's example, they use a method called `setQ("query")`, but that only works in Java. Does someone knows how to set this parameter in C#?

**Edit:**
In Java, would be like this: `service.users().messages().list("me").setQ("is:chat").execute();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I feel kind of dumb right now, the answer was very simple. It just requires to separate the call in three lines:

```
ListRequest request = service.Users.Messages.List("me");
request.Q = "is:chat";
ListMessagesResponse response = await request.Execute();
```

Comment: In my defense, I have to say that Google's documentation is very brief and lacks explanations, especially in regards to. NET

Comment: Don't feel dumb. I had the same exact problem. Thanks for sharing!